# iphone simulator shaking has no function

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Hello everyone
I hoped to test the shaking function on simulator,
so in the Hardware menu, I choose Shake Gesture.
But nothing happened, what wrong?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Marc

Comment: can you post some of your shaking code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking "Shake Gesture" in the iPhone simulator doesn't play an animation—perhaps this is why it seems not to be doing anything?

You can receive notification of shake events in your code by implementing `motionEnded:withEvent:` in a `UIResponder` subclass. For example, if you were to create a custom `UIWindow` subclass:

```
// ShakeWindow.h
@interface ShakeWindow : UIWindow
@end

// ShakeWindow.m
#import "ShakeWindow.h"

@implementation ShakeWindow

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    NSLog(@"Shake!");
  }
}

@end
```

For more information, see the [Motion Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) section of Apple's Event Handling Guide for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"shake");
        //your code
    }

}
```